# Extract Image from payload XHR post request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a chrome extension that should get an image before it is uploaded using a post request from a website.

What I am doing is that I have created a `XMLHttpRequest hook`. Whenever a particular request occurs for post, the callback is invoked and I can access the data being requested. This is my code.

```
var s_ajaxListener = new Object();
s_ajaxListener.tempOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
s_ajaxListener.tempSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
s_ajaxListener.callback = function () {
  // this.method :the ajax method used
  // this.url    :the url of the requested script (including query string, if any) (urlencoded) 
  // this.data   :the data sent, if any ex: foo=bar&a=b (urlencoded)
}

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(a,b) {
  if (!a) var a='';
  if (!b) var b='';
  s_ajaxListener.tempOpen.apply(this, arguments);
  s_ajaxListener.method = a;  
  s_ajaxListener.url = b;
  console.log(this);
  if (a.toLowerCase() == 'get') {
    s_ajaxListener.data = b.split('?');
    s_ajaxListener.data = s_ajaxListener.data[1];
  }
}

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(a,b) {
  if (!a) var a='';
  if (!b) var b='';
  s_ajaxListener.tempSend.apply(this, arguments);
  if(s_ajaxListener.method.toLowerCase() == 'post')s_ajaxListener.data = a;
  s_ajaxListener.callback();
}
```

`this.data` in the callback has the requested data. Its type is arraybuffer.

The problem is that when I convert this buffer into a blob and try to render the image, it always comes broken. I am banging my head against the wall.

I checked and the image binary is always being sent in the `Request Payload`. Screenshot attached[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Why the arraybuffer always leads to a corrupted image? Is there a way I can monitor the payload being sent and extract image from there?

Comment: The request is probably sending more than just the image ... It's a multipart request, so you have to split it at the boundaries first to get to the individual parts ...

Comment: @CBroe thats what I thought. Can you please help me out on where to start? Actually I am not very familiar about the parts that makeup a multipart request

Comment: Usually this would be done on the server, and not in client-side JavaScript. But if you research how this is done using server-side JavaScript (node.js), this could probably give some hints on how to do this.